# Error in installing openVPN module in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to connect Sophos VPN using nodejs. For this I am referring below link
https://github.com/luigiplr/node-openvpn
So while executing npm install node-openvpn --save command I am getting error. Can anyone please help me with this issue? Below is the screenshot of error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XkVR.png)

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular the part about not posting pictures of text.

Answer (score -1):

Clean your cache and try again:

```
    npm cache clean --force
    npm install node-openvpn --save
```